# How to enable On Screen Keybord (OSK.exe) When a texbox is highlighted

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I wrote a VB 6 application for Windows 7 touch screen, how can I call the On Screen Keyboard (OSK.exe) when user point on the text box?

With windows 7 and Windows touch it will not have any problem, but the problem is the Windows touch pack cannot be installed into the touch screen that does not support double simultaneous touch.

Answer (score 0):

We have an industrial machinery software we develop that runs on touchscreen.
We just have our own form that has every key on it that when closed returns the value back to the textbox.

Comment: How can I write a form just like OSK.exe using sendkeys?